# Working with very small numbers in python

Tags: python

I am using python and have something like this-

```
a=3.472556691305291e-97
b=2.0842803001689662e-120

c=a/(a+b)
print(c)
```

I am getting `value=1.0` . But I want the exact answer.Is there some way I can improve my accuracy here?

Comment: what is the desired type of the result? the exact fraction equals to `1.0` as a float: `float(Fraction(1736278345652645500000000000000000000000, 1736278345652645500000010421401500844831)) == 1`

Comment: The desired type is float only

Comment: If the result is `float` then `1.0` is the best you can get.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an external library, such as [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/), to get arbitrary precision floating point numbers.

Use the [`mpf`](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/basics.html#number-types) type for the numbers, as shown in the examples in the documentation:

```
>>> mpf(4)
mpf('4.0')
>>> mpf(2.5)
mpf('2.5')
>>> mpf("1.25e6")
mpf('1250000.0')
>>> mpf(mpf(2))
mpf('2.0')
>>> mpf("inf")
mpf('+inf')
```

Comment: what is the reason not to use `decimal` or `fractions` module from stdlib here?